# Python concating lists of specific list to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a list of lists of dataframes.

```
Biglist = [[dfA1, dfB11,dfB12][dfA2, dfB21,dfB22][dfA3, dfB31,dfB32][dfA4, dfB41,dfB42]]
```

I want to create a data frame of A's from all sublists in the above list.

My expected output

```
df_A = concating dfA1 to dfA4
```

My present code

```
df_A = [pd.concat(Biglist[i][0],axis=1) for i in range(0,len(Biglist[i]),1)]
```

My present output

```
TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the iterator in the first argument to `pd.concat()`. Also, it doesn't need to be inside another list.

```
df_A = pd.concat((l[0] for l in BigList), axis=0)
```

I also recommend you get used to using `for var in listname` rather than `for i in range(len(listname))`. It makes the code simpler and clearer. If you also need the indexes for something, use `enumerate()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and inputs. Your code did concat the first dataframes in all sublists. Each `dfA` has one column with same name. After concatnating I should see one column but I am seeing four  columns all having same names. Am I missing something above?

Comment: What were you expecting instead?

Comment: I'm not a pandas expert, but maybe you used the wrong axis.

Comment: After a trial and error, I found the answer and it is simple. Just removing the `axis=1` solved it. Thanks. It is default set to `axis=0`